# Error handler from tomcat to jetty

Tags: java, jsp, error-handling, jetty

I'm trying migrate webapp from tomcat to jetty (with jetty-runner) and this is the problem:

In any class in my rest api I throw an Exception and in my tomcat, I had configured an error jsp to process, parse and to return a specific formatted message with json syntax. The configuration in tomcat had web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>errorJSP</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/errors.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>errorJSP</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/error</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

Now, I launch the webapp with jetty and this configuration don't run. After throw exception, the rest api return 500 and the execution don't pass by my jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me in my app on Jetty:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: This trace appears in log: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container